# How do I enable logging in the Asterisk.NET library?

Tags: c#, asterisk

I am writing a FastAGI script that utilizes the Asterisk.NET assembly to handle the AGI portions.  I've seen in the Asterisk.NET script references to the "Logger" object, which should be providing me with a ton of Debug info, but I've got nothing in the application output.

I've resorted to using `Console.WriteLine`'s to drop some debug information, but at this point I've got an Exception that I can't print info about as the Asterisk.NET FastAGI handler appears to silently sequester all exceptions, rather than letting them crash and give me the info I need to fix them!

Does anyone know how I can enable the Logger class properly?  Failing that, does anyone know how I can instruct the Asterisk.NET library to NOT silently discard exceptions?  I'm having trouble finding the answer in both cases.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the project's properties, the tab named Build, and write LOGGER into the "Conditional compilation symbols". The Logger class is contained in Asterisk.NET.

Comment: Thanks for this, however I'm using mono rather than MS .NET, which probably would have been a great thing for me to include in the above post.  I'll try compiling it with flag LOGGER and see what happens.  Thanks for the tip.